# Windows subsystem for linux ubuntu xfce error

Tags: xfce

@DESKTOP-G8IPC93:~$ xfce4-session
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.

how to fix this error!!!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Subsystem for Linux is not designed for running Linux Desktop Environments like XFCE. It is possible to export the display of applications to an X server running on Windows, such as [VCXSRV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/). However, there is no guarantee it will work properly.

If you need a functional Linux desktop inside of Windows, you need to run a virtual machine inside of Hyper-V or VirtualBox.